# Function inside the same function PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, loops

I'm busy with cleaning a WordPress parse_blocks() array.

Array:
Parse blocks

- blockName
- attrs
- innerBlocks (0)

InnerBlocks (0)

- blockName
- attrs
- innerBlocks (1)

InnerBlocks (1)

- blockName
- attrs
- innerBlocks (2)

What I want is making a function which repeats each innerblock.
As you see above the array Parse block has innerblocks and those can get also innerblocks (2 times).

I made a simple function cleanBlock($block)

```
function cleanBlock($block)
{
    if (isset($block['blockName']) && $block['blockName'] != '') {
        $splitType = explode('/', $block['blockName']);
        $innerBlocks = $block['innerBlocks'];
        $block = array(
            'type' => $splitType[1],
            'attrs' => '',
            'innerblocks' => $innerBlocks,
        );
        return $block;
    }
}
```

There you find "innerblock"  my idea was to run the cleanBlock($innerBlocks) again, but if I do that it doesn't work because the $block is made before I can get the innerblock, it's hard to explain I hope you know what I mean.

This is what I want, but this code doesn't work at all:

```
function cleanBlock($block)
{
    if (isset($block['blockName']) && $block['blockName'] != '') {
        $splitType = explode('/', $block['blockName']);
        $block = array(
            'type' => $splitType[1],
            'attrs' => '',
            'innerblocks' => cleanBlock($block['innerBlocks']),
        );
        return $block;
    }
}
```

After the function I make the final array:

```
$newPDFarray = [];
foreach ($parseBlocks as $key => $group) {
    $block = cleanBlock($group);
    $newPDFarray[] = $block;
}
```

Comment: Note that `innerblocks` is not the same as `innerBlocks` in `'innerblocks' => cleanBlock($block['innerBlocks']),`

Comment: Can you be more specific? How exactly does your existing code not work? It looks like you’re trying to define a recursive function without defining a base case - you need some conditional to prevent infinite recursion, ie only call `cleanBlock` if `innerBlocks` is set.

Comment: I can give it a try, the last code you see that i look over the $parseBlocks and in those $parseBlocks there you find 'innerblocks' there he needs to do the same function again

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the right or short solution but for me it works:

```
function cleanBlock($block)
{
    if (isset($block['blockName']) && $block['blockName'] != '') {
        $splitType = explode('/', $block['blockName']);

        $innerBlocks = [];
        foreach ($block['innerBlocks'] as $block) {
            $innerBlocks[] = cleanBlock($block);
        }

        $block = array(
            'type' => $splitType[1],
            'attrs' => $block['attrs'],
            'innerBlocks' => $innerBlocks,
        );
        return $block;
    }
}

$newPDFarray = [];
foreach ($parseBlocks as $key => $group) {
    if ($group['blockName'] != '') {
        $questionGroup = cleanBlock($group);
        $newPDFarray[] = $questionGroup;
    }
}
```